# Any thought of bringing back the podcast?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, podcast

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bring back the podcast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79649/bring-back-the-podcast)

Any thought of bringing back the podcast?  I miss the once a week dose of Jeff & Joel.

Update: still missing it

Answer (score 14):

I posted this [on the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/stack-exchange-on-herding-code/#comment-48295), but I'll repost it here: I really miss the podcast. If Joel doesn’t want to continue with it, there are now plenty of other valued associates that can continue in his place. I, for one, would like to hear from the new hires, what they’re working on, etc.

Comment: I even want to hear [Robert Cartaino](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino) talk about the community and building great sites!

Answer (score 1):

*The following answer was originally posted [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79649/bring-back-the-podcast/87432#87432) by Ray Vega*

[According to Joel](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/welcome-valued-associate-alex-miller/), it appears that the podcasts will be returning:

> In the coming months you’ll see
> several amazing things that Alex has
> started doing, including the
> resurgence of Stack Overflow DevDays,
> **the renewal of my podcast with Jeff**, and an amazing thing, still
> secret, involving unicorns.